# Mu4e: How to keep the currently opened mail centered in the headers view?

Tags: mu4e

When reading mail in the split headers/view in mu4e, is it possible to keep the currently opened mail [centered](https://ibb.co/pd8qxbQ) in the headers view instead of at the [bottom](https://ibb.co/TtFKN2Q)?

It would be nice to show some context on the mail thread even through `mu4e-view-headers-next`, `mu4e-view-mark-for-trash` or even `mu4e-view-headers-next-unread`